# How to return value from a method

Tags: java

I'm stuck with this problem in a method. The idea is make a dicerolls counter. I made a function called `rolldice();` and I want to use it in the main. I used a while into the main and I want to make a count return, but I don't know where is the problem. Does anyone know it please?

```
  static int rolldice(){
    double randomnum=Math.random();
    randomnum=randomnum*6;
    randomnum=randomnum+1;
    int randomint =(int) randomnum;
    return randomint;


}
public static int  main(String[] args) {
    int roll1= rolldice();
    int roll2=rolldice();
    int count=1;
    while(!(roll1==roll2)) {
        roll1=rolldice();
        roll2=rolldice();
        count=count+1;

    }
    return count;

}
```

Comment: Java's `main` method doesn't return anything (it should have a `void` return type). You can print `count` instead of returning it.

Comment: And please read [mcve] for future questions. "doesn't work" isn't a working problem description!

Comment: What should happen with the value of `count`? Where do you expect it to go, once it was returned from `main()`? In which way are you executing this program? How do you expect to notice that e.g. a 500 was returned and not a 10? Is there any second program which you expect to be aware of the value after executing this program?

Comment: ah i use the math.random that give you random number between 0 and 0.9999999999

Answer (score 0, accepted):

main() method in java can't return a value. Instead of that you can create another method that can return int value as shown here. Now, you can call that method anywhere according to your task and it will return the count value.

```
static int rolldice(){
    double randomnum=Math.random();
    randomnum=randomnum*6;
    randomnum=randomnum+1;
    int randomint =(int) randomnum;
    return randomint;        
}
public static void main(String[] args) {    

}

public static int roll(){

    int roll1= rolldice();
    int roll2=rolldice();
    int count=1;
    while(!(roll1==roll2)) {
        roll1=rolldice();
        roll2=rolldice();
        count=count+1;

    }
    return count;
}
```

Comment: it's so amazing thank you so much and sorry if i bother you

Answer (score 1):

A small modification and clean up to your code, as everyone said main will not have return type and it will not return anything, in that case you need to declare your own method with return type and should return from it

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
int roll1= (int) (Math.random()*6+1);
int roll2= (int) (Math.random()*6+1);
int total=rollDice(roll1,roll2);
System.out.println(total);
 }

 public static int rollDice(int roll1, int roll2) {
    int count=0;
    while(!(roll1==roll2)) {
        roll1=(int) (Math.random()*6+1);
        roll2=(int) (Math.random()*6+1);
        count++;

    }
    return count;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't work because the main method is a void so you can't return `count` with it because it is an int

Comment: `public static int  main(String[] args)` I believe you meant to say the main method should be void

Comment: @JacobBoertjes yes